# laravel belongstomany with condition

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-4

I have the following model.

```
class Training extends \Eloquent {

    // Add your validation rules here
    public static $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
        'province' => 'required',
        'budget_year' => 'required|integer',
        's_date' => 'required|date',
        'e_date' => 'required|date'
    ];

    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'city',
        'province',
        'budget_year',
        's_date',
        'e_date'
    ];

    public function material(){
        return $this->hasMany('Material');
    }

    public function budget(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Budget')->withPivot('amount');
    }

    public function budgetById($training_id){
        $this->belongsToMany('Budget')->where('training_id', '=', $training_id)->get();
    }

}
```

when I debug the `budgetById` method using `DB::getQueryLog`, the query is as follow

```
select budgets.*, 
budget_training.training_id as pivot_training_id, 
budget_training.budget_id as pivot_budget_id 
from budgets inner join budget_training on budgets.id = budget_training.budget_id 
where budget_training.training_id is null and training_id='6'
```

which return 0 rows, but when I try to modify the query and run it in pgadmin, the following script works well.

```
select budgets.*, 
budget_training.training_id as pivot_training_id, 
budget_training.budget_id as pivot_budget_id 
from budgets inner join budget_training on budgets.id = budget_training.budget_id 
where budget_training.training_id='6'
```

notice I remove `training_id is null and` from Laravel generated query. What is wrong with my `budgetById` method?

Answer (score 21):

You have called `get()` and didn't use `return` here:

```
public function budgetById($training_id){
    // = in where is optional in this case
    $this->belongsToMany('Budget')->where('training_id', '=', $training_id);
}
```

You should use like this:

```
public function budgetById($training_id){
    // = in where is optional in this case
    return $this->belongsToMany('Budget')->where('training_id', '=', $training_id);
}
```

Comment: You don't need `=` as if there are only 2 parameters on `where()`, `=` is implied

Comment: Can I add more than one `where clause` ?

Comment: Yes you can @AyazShah

Comment: How can I use this budgetById in `with` function?

Comment: `YourModel::with('budgetById')`

Comment: Hi @alpha how can we pass the training id?

Answer (score 5):

In Lavarel 7.X, you can use the `wherePivot` method to filter columns on the **pivot table**, like this:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Budget')->wherePivot('training_id', '=', $training_id);
```

or

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Budget')->wherePivotNotNull('training_id');
```